# How to integrate Azure ACS with local (custom) STS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, wif

What would be best practice to integrate Azure ACS with local custom authentication in ASP.NET MVC application running on Azure? So basically the requirement is that web application must have custom authentication and must also support main identity provides.

I think the best approach is to use Azure ACS (to nicely support main identity provides) and since ACS in based on WIF (Identity Foundation) it would nicely fit with local STS.

What are your recommendations about this approach? Do you have better suggestions? Do you maybe have any examples how to integrate ACS with local STS?

Do I thinking wrong and those entities (ACS and local STS) are completely separated? And those are not have to be aware of each other? This would make sense to me.

I am new to the Azure ACS in WIF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes, this is all possible. The "local STS" part is the one that might or might not be necessary. If you wanted to keep your own authentication, you don;t necessarily need your own STS to do so. I would start with the simplest thing possible: an MVC app relying on an STS (e.g. first a local one, then ACS, then maybe both).

There're many examples [here](http://claimsid.codeplex.com).